# Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined как исправить в массиве объектов?

Tags: javascript

Задача с лампами: в поле вводится кол-во лампочек, и после нажатия на кнопку они должны появиться и начать мигать.
Проблема: при вводе больше 1 происходит ошибка

```
"Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined"
```

```js
const divlamp = '<div id="lamp"></div>';
        function Lamp(lamp, color, interval){
            this.lamp = document.getElementById(lamp);
            this.isOn = true;
            this.color = color;
            this.interval = interval;
            this.switch = function(){
                if(this.isOn==true){
                    this.lamp.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }else {
                    this.lamp.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
                }
                this.isOn = !this.isOn;
            }
            this.work = function(){
                setInterval(this.switch, this.interval);
            }
        }
        start = function(){
            let lamps = [];
            let kolvo = document.getElementById("kol").value;
            for(let i=0; i<kolvo; i++){
             document.getElementById("girlyand").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",divlamp);
             lamps.push(new Lamp("lamp","blue", 1000));
             lamps[i].work();
            }  
        }
```

```css
#lamp{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input id="kol"><button onclick="start()">OK</button>
 
  <div id="girlyand">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const divlamp = '<div id="lamp"></div>';

function Lamp(lamp, color, interval) {
  this.lamp = document.getElementById(lamp);
  this.isOn = true;
  this.color = color;
  this.interval = interval;
  this.switch = function() {
    if (this.isOn == true) {
      this.lamp.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
      this.lamp.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    }
    this.isOn = !this.isOn;
  }
  this.work = function() {
    setInterval(this.switch.bind(this), this.interval);
  }
}
start = function() {
  let lamps = [];
  let kolvo = document.getElementById("kol").value;
  for (let i = 0; i < kolvo; i++) {
    document.getElementById("girlyand").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", divlamp);
    lamps.push(new Lamp("lamp", "blue", 1000));
    lamps[i].work();
  }
}
```

```css
#lamp {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<input id="kol" value=3><button onclick="start()">OK</button>

<div id="girlyand"></div>
```

Comment: а почему просто не добавить вызов функции в setInterval(this.switch(), this.interval); ?

Comment: @VasiliAnoshin Например, потому что функция `switch` ничего не возвращает, а первым параметром в `setInterval` надо передать ссылку на функцию.